# Activity's launch modes

Tags: android, android-activity

As described in figure4 [on here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html), Activity Y in task B will be brought front when activity2 in Task A startActivityY.

What will happen if Activity is not at the top of task B when Activity 2 startActivityY. ?

Answer (score 0):

It says right in the text:

> In this case, when Task B is brought forward to handle a new intent,
>   the BACK key first navigates backward through the activities in Task B
>   before returning to the top-most activity in Task A.

Comment: thank you. in this example activity is on the top of task B, so activity Y handle the intent and be brought foreground. i want to know if activity Y was not on the top of task B, the system how to dispose this when Activity start Activity Y? Activity is not at the top of task B, how did it being brought foreground?